# Flip SVG Half Circle

Tags: svg, path, automatic-ref-counting

I would like to flip this SVG Path horizontally so that the curved arc is facing down. Any help would be greatly appreciated in adjusting the coordinates...

Here is what I got so far:

```
    <style>
    .circular path {
    fill: #3498db;
    stroke: #3498db;
    }
    </style>
    <svg class="circular border_blue" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="80" viewBox="0 0 100 80" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C40 0 60 0 100 100 Z">
    </path>
    </svg>
```

Comment: If you want to flip something apply a transform to it either transform="scale(-1, 1)" or transform="scale(1, -1)" depending on the axis you want to flip it over. You may need to add a translate to move it to where you want it to be once you've flipped it round the origin.

Comment: Did you post the wrong SVG?  Your path isn't a half circle, or a "curved arc".  It is just a straight line,

Comment: Fixed path above...would prefer to write path correctly instead of doing a CSS Transform.